# postfix limit sending rate

Tags: postfix, centos5

hello i have this box

centos 5.9
postfix 2.3.3

how i can configure postfix to send 1 message every second
no matter what, i try this in main.cf with no success:

```
default_destination_rate_delay = 1s  
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 1  
default_destination_recipient_limit = 2  
initial_destination_concurrency = 1
```

What i'm missing ?
thanks

**UPDATE**

I try last night:

```
initial_destination_concurrency=1  
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 1  
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
```

with no success mail

### Per-Hour Traffic Summary

```
time          received  delivered   deferred    bounced     rejected
0300-0400           0       9132      45000        286          0
0400-0500           1      22832         67        223          0
0500-0600           0      19000      15410         93          0
```

The problem, hotmail blacklisted to us, or queue begin to grow and grow (deferred),
when hotmail remove the blacklisted, postfix begin to send all deferred queue emails, like a earthquake.

this is why i think if i configure postfix to send one email every second, the problem disappear

any ideas ? thanks

Comment: But why this strange requirement? All mail admins will try to tune an MTA to reduce the delivery latency.

Comment: I can't answer what you need to do, but it would seem that your configuration is only looking at emails sent per server.  Have you looked at "Cluebringer" (policyd) - that has rate limiting and management of concurrent sending - I suspect that it won't answer your stated requirement of 1 email per second, but may solve your class of problem if its spam / sending rate related.

Comment: I think the solution is to find out why hotmail blacklisted you, remove the offending emails from the queue, jump on whoever it was that caused the problem and implement cluebringer to limit concurrency etc.  The problem is unlikely to disappear by sending 1 email a second, although it might buy you a bit of time/mitigate the problem - but it doesn't address the root issue.

Comment: thanks david, the problem is we send a lot of emails and normally the 80%  databases are hotmail, every machine can send 35000 emails per day with no issue, but when we pass that limit, hotmail close the emails reception, PD (we are in JMR program, sdns, valid SPF records), i will try cluebringer but a great software like postifx must have some extra tuning feature... thanks

Answer (score 2):

_destination_concurrency_limit needs to be > 1.

Value 1 will cause the destination to be full email, value >1 will cause the destination match the email domain. However the destination_rate_relay when set will always send one at a time.

> default_destination_concurrency_limit (default: 20)
>
> The default maximal number of parallel deliveries to the same destination. This is the default limit for delivery via the lmtp(8),
>   pipe(8), smtp(8) and virtual(8) delivery agents. With per-destination
>   recipient limit > 1, a destination is a domain, otherwise it is a
>   recipient.

try

> smtp_destination_recipient_limit = 2
>
> smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
>
> smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s